# Actions on Twitter custom timeline

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I built a custom Twitter timeline based on the OAuth lib. And then output all things that I need, except for Twitter actions like "retweet", "reply", "favorite", etc.
How can I implementat all these actions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question a bit. I find it somewhat confusing though; you didn't need things like Retweet, then want to build them? Also, it might help if you showed us some of your code. Also, you mention OAuth in the tags; do you have problems with OAuth? If so, please edit them into the post. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution it`s looks like this

(in your foreach loop from oauth connection)

```
<a target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id={$tweet->id_str}'><i class='fa fa-retweet'></i> {$tweet->retweet_count}</a
```